# Python decode in unicode variable with non-ascii character or without

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii

A simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import traceback

e_u = u'abc'
c_u = u'中国'

print sys.getdefaultencoding()
try:
    print e_u.decode('utf-8')
    print c_u.decode('utf-8')
except Exception as e:
    print traceback.format_exc()

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
try:
    print e_u.decode('utf-8')
    print c_u.decode('utf-8')
except Exception as e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

output:

```
ascii
abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_codec.py", line 15, in <module>
    print c_u.decode('utf-8')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

utf-8
abc
中国
```

Some problems troubled me a few days when I want to thoroughly understand the codec in python, and I want to make sure what I think is right:

1. Under `ascii` default encoding, `u'abc'.decode('utf-8')` have no error, but `u'中国'.decode('utf-8')` have error.

   I think when do `u'中国'.decode('utf-8')`, Python check and found `u'中国'` is unicode, so it try to do `u'中国'.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())`, this will cause problem, and the exception is `UnicodeEncodeError`, not error when decode.

   but `u'abc'` have the same code point as `'abc'` ( < 128), so there is no error.
2. In Python 2.x, how does python inner store variable value? If all characters in a string < 128, treat as `ascii`, if > 128, treat as `utf-8`?

   ```
   In [4]: chardet.detect('abc')
   Out[4]: {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}

   In [5]: chardet.detect('abc中国')
   Out[5]: {'confidence': 0.7525, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}

   In [6]: chardet.detect('中国')
   Out[6]: {'confidence': 0.7525, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

You have to use `encode()`, or leave it out. Don't use `decode()` with unicode strings, that makes no sense. Also, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` doesn't help here in any way.

**Long answer, part 1: How to do it correctly?**

If you define:

```
c_u = u'中国'
```

then `c_u` is already a unicode string, that is, it has already been decoded from byte string (of your source file) to a unicode string by the Python interpreter, using your `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` declaration.

If you execute:

```
print c_u.encode()
```

your string will be encoded back to UTF-8 and that byte string is sent to the standard output. Note that this usually happens automatically for you, so you can simplify this to:

```
print c_u
```

**Long answer, part 2: What's wrong with c_u.decode()?**

If you execute `c_u.decode()`, Python will

1. Try to convert your object (i.e. your unicode string) to a byte string
2. Try to decode that byte string to a unicode string

Note that this doesn't make any sense if your object is a unicode string in the first place - you just convert it forth and back. But why does that fail? Well, this is a strange functionality of Python that first step (1.), i.e. any *implicit* conversion from unicode string to byte strings, usually uses sys.getdefaultencoding(), which in turn defaults to the ASCII character set. In other words,

```
c_u.decode()
```

translates roughly to:

```
c_u.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).decode()
```

which is why it fails.

Note that while you may be tempted to change that default encoding, don't forget that other third-party libraries may contain similar issues, and might break if the default encoding is different from ASCII.

Having said that, I strongly believe that Python would be better off if they hadn't defined `unicode.decode()` in the first place. Unicode string are already decoded, there's no point in decoding them once more, especially in the way Python does.

Comment: I know should use `encode`, my problem is why use decode on u'abc' have no problem, and what I think is right?

Comment: See the second part of my answer, where I describe how `unicode.decode()` behaves internally. This should make clear why `u'abc'.decode()` accidentally works.

Comment: The part 2 you said, I think error: `any implicit conversion from unicode string to byte strings, always uses the ASCII character set.`. See the example code I asked, If I change the default encoding to utf-8, it's ok.

Comment: @TankyWoo: You are right. I changed "always" to "usually". I guess only a Python hacker (i.e. a developer of Python itself) can describe this mechanism in full detail.

Comment: `c_u.encode()` uses default encoding that is 'ascii' on Python 2.

Comment: you should mention that there is no `.decode()` method for Unicode strings in Python 3.

Comment: *"usually uses the ASCII character set."* -- it uses `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. You should mention that changing the default encoding is not recommended. It may break 3rd party libraries that do not expect it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the hint. I incorporated it, and I also changed the answer to a community wiki, so others can add details and make corrections on their own. This is really a tricky topic.